# Не могу запустить Django-блог на сервере

Tags: python, django

Мешает следующая ошибка:

```
  File "/root/pyserver/news/news/urls.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
ImportError: cannot import name patterns
```

Не на сервере(на localhost) работет все хорошо.

Comment: Проверь, какие версии Джанго установлены локально и на сервере. Скорее всего дело в том, что они разные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В официальной [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/urls/) Django есть предупреждение по этому поводу

```
Deprecated since version 1.8:
urlpatterns should be a plain list of django.conf.urls.url() instances instead.
```

Соответственно поправьте ваши urls - теперь они должны выглядеть так

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', ArticleView.as_view()),
]
```

К слову автоматические импорты через строку тоже удаляют. Теперь надо явно прописывать

```
from news.views import year_archive
...
url(r'^articles/([0-9]{4})/$', year_archive),
```

Answer (score 1):

Информации маловато, но вывод можно сделать такой: на сервере старая версия Django. Структуру модуля поменяли в версии 1.4 - https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.9/releases/1.4/#django-conf-urls-defaults. Соответсвенно, **в версиях < 1.4** проблемная строка должна выглядеть следующим образом:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, url, include
```

Comment: В 1.10 вообще удалили patterns, теперь там обычные массивы